# I want to Rename multiple folders

Tags: windows

I'm renaming over a 1000 folders.  Now they're named CD# - Artist - Album name and I wish to name them Artist - CD# - Album name so I can sort them by Artist.

Comment: There are third party bulk rename programs that may or may not work for you. Research on "bulk rename files".  Otherwise this is not a native Windows capability.

Comment: This may be what you are looking for:  https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort them by Artist why don't you add the Artist column in  File Explorer and sort the files by that column?

But if you really want to rename you could create a batch file that does the renaming. You open notepad, put the code below, save as somename.bat and drag the folder with the music albums to the batch file.

```
@echo off

IF /i exist "%~1" set "Folder=%~1" else Exit
cd /d "%Folder%"
for /f "Delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b') do for /f "tokens=1-2* Delims=-" %%b in ("%%a") do call :Rename "%%~a" "%%~b" "%%~c" "%%~d"
exit

:Rename
set "Artist=%~3"
IF "%Artist:~0,1%"==" " Set "Artist=%Artist:~1%"
if not "%~4"=="" (ren "%~1" "%Artist%- %~2-%~4") else (ren "%~1" "%Artist% - %~2")
goto :EOF
```

[Artist.gif](https://i.imgur.com/Wye34ok.gif)

Comment: Thank you so much.  I had already done about 450 out of 1300 one at a time, THANKS!

Comment: I checked again and it looks like sort by Artist column only works for files not folders (at least on my test), also if you have folders with a porcentage sign "%" like:  "CD1 - Rihanna - 100% Rihanna (2019)" the batch will crash....

Comment: Well, fortunately I don't have that CD, LOL.  I copied your .bat file into Notebook, named it namechange.bat and dropped it into a test folder with 5 files in it and it worked great.  One thing I found though, you can't have other folders in there, it screws them up.  I already knew that there was no Artist column in folder view...wish there was some way to add it.

Comment: What do you mean with: You can't have other folders in there? Folders that should not be renamed?

Comment: Folders not in the same format, for example, ones not burnt to a CD so not having a CD# yet.

Comment: Is it actually CD# or CD + Number ?

Comment: Just a number - Artist - Title, but if there's not a number then the batch file switches the first & last names of the artist.

Comment: I've got a program called MP3tag that's great for editing the tags on song titles and I've learned to manipulate those pretty well (with a lot of help from the help files).  It does a great job of switchint the name to last name, first name and automatically filling some fields of the tags.  It's a free program and I donate occasionally...